# .NET MAUI iOS Notifications

Tags: ios, maui

I am building a MAUI app for iOS and Android. It will connect to a SignalR hub and receive data sporadically, but when it does I want to notify the user.

I am an Android user and haven't much experience with Apple stuff so I'm not familiar with how iOS things work.

I have read up on the various iOS `backgrounding` techniques [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/) however I'm still unsure on how to proceed.

***Opportunistic background*** tasks sound like they'll check too infrequently and might be delayed in notifying the user.

***Background Fetch*** might be an option, I see that it's possible to have some influence over the interval for fetches and that the UI can be updated with received data.

***Background Transfers*** probably aren't relevant for me since they're meant for larger data transfers.

There is a walkthrough [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-walkthroughs/location-walkthrough) on using location when the app is in the background.

I haven't been able to figure out whether the app will be able to display notifications while the app is in the background. i.e put a message on the screen to tell the user there is some new data

I assume it's possible and that the above links and things I've read are saying it's possible, but I'm still not sure.

Comment: I can't really tell what your requirements are.  You mention Notifications, but it seems like the core issue is receiving SignalR messages while backgrounded?   There are quite a few [existing questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=signalr+ios+background+site:stackoverflow.com) on the subject

Comment: I guess I'm confused about how to make an iOS app that's able to receive data while in the background.
I think I have read that you can register for notifications from an apple service. You then receive a message via that and then handle that message by going to get the updated data. So.. it won't be a SignalR client running 24x7 since that would be terminated by the OS. But it will get the job done.